# Can I use wildcards in Firebird POSITION function

Tags: sql, firebird, text-parsing, firebird2.1

I am using Firebird 2.1.

I have job order number that may have 1 or 2 alpha characters then 4 or 5 numbers then maybe a prefix with 1 alpha character and 2 numbers.

I want to extract the 4-5 digit number in the middle.

I tried the following to find the number char, but it returned 0:

`POSITION('%[0-9]%',JOBHEADER.ORDERNUMBER,1) AS "FIRST NUMBER"`

I am not sure if I can use wildcards with the `POSITION` function. I guess I could try and check the 2nd or 3rd character for a number, but I really need the wild card feature to then find the next alpha after I find the position of the first number. Or maybe there is another solution to extract the number.

I have found something simliar:

```sql
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(ordernumber FROM 2 FOR 5) SIMILAR TO '[0-9]+'
     THEN SUBSTRING(ordernumber FROM 2 FOR 5)
     ELSE SUBSTRING(ordernumber FROM 3 FOR 5)
END as PROJECTNUMBER
```

But with the number possibly starting in the first 5 chars then a if/case statement starts getting quite big.

Comment: `then maybe a prefix with 1 alpha character` - "then" means "after", and PREfixes go *before* main value, not after. Those that after go as POSTfixes usually. So, give the example input and output data please. // Personally, for parsing, i would write a Stored Procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do this with `POSITION`. Position searches for the exact substring in a given string. However, with Firebird 3, you could use [`SUBSTRING`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-dml-substring) with regular expressions to extract the value, for example:

```
substring(ordernumber similar '%#"[[:DIGIT:]]+#"%' escape '#')
```

The regular expression must cover the entire string, while the `#"` encloses the term to extract (the `#` is the explicitly defined escape symbol). You may need to use more complex patterns like `[^[:DIGIT:]]*#"[[:DIGIT:]]+#"([^[:DIGIT:]]%)?` to avoid edge-cases in greediness.

If you know the pattern is always 1 or 2 alpha, 4 or 5 digits you want to extract, possibly followed by 1 alpha and 2 numbers, you could also use `[[:ALPHA:]]{1,2}#"[[:DIGIT:]]{4,5}#"([[:ALPHA:]][[:DIGIT:]]{1,2})?`. If the pattern isn't matched `null` is returned.

See also:

- [README.substring_similar.txt](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/master/doc/sql.extensions/README.substring_similar.txt)
- [regular expression syntax](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-syntaxregex)

Be aware that the SQL standard regular expression syntax supported by Firebird is a bit odd, and less powerful than regular expressions common in other languages.

### Using PSQL

To solve this using PSQL, under Firebird 2.1, you can use something like:

```
create or alter procedure extract_number(input_value varchar(50)) 
    returns (output_value bigint)
as
declare char_position integer = 0;
declare number_string varchar(20) = '';
declare current_char char(1);
begin
  while (char_position < char_length(input_value)) do
  begin
    char_position = char_position + 1;
    current_char = substring(input_value from char_position for 1);
    if ('0' <= current_char and current_char <= '9') then
    begin
      number_string = number_string || current_char;
    end
    else if (char_length(number_string) > 0) then
    begin
      -- switching from numeric to non-numeric, found first number occurrence in string
      leave;
    end
  end
  output_value = iif(char_length(number_string) > 0, cast(number_string as bigint), null);
end
```

Comment: problem is, he explicitly mentioned FB 2.1 not 3+ // this however leads to the question what exactly is the problem and what exactly qualifies for an answer...

Comment: @Arioch'The The immediate answer to the question (which is _"Can I use wildcards in Firebird POSITION function"_) is _"No you can't do this with `POSITION`."_. The rest of the answer provides an alternative that is available on Firebird 3.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  Could I write a trigger that would use a WHILE to loop through each character in the job number string to find the first digit, then add that to a variable and continue until a non digit character was reached. Then assign that variable to a field? This would achieve the same end result. But rather than trying to get the number via a select statement, I am getting it when the data is entered into the table.

Comment: Actually it's similar to what @Arioch'The mentioned in his comment to my question, but since I have never written a procedure, then trigger might be a better solution for me.

Comment: @SimonKing Yes, that is possible to do. I'll see if I can add an example of doing that when I have time.

Comment: @SimonKing I added an example to extract it in PSQL on Firebird 2.1. I noticed that the `SIMILAR TO` you are using in your question was introduced in Firebird 2.5, so you are likely using Firebird 2.5, not 2.1